# Error in Python Playwright: playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at ... waiting until "load" error Python Playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I've struggled a while now trying to download a pdf in Python Playwright which is rendered from a php web page (not included in this example as it has sensitive code - instead I've included a link to a pdf).

Here's my code so far, using the JavaScript code from https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/3509 as example:

```
from playwright.async_api import Playwright, async_playwright, expect
import asyncio
import os
import json

tmp_dir = './pwtest/'
user_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","user_dir")
print("User dir: ", user_dir)
downloads_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","downloads")
print("Downloads path: ", downloads_path)
storage_state_path = "./pwtest/"

default_preferences = {
    "plugins": {
        "always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
}
#Making directories can likely be done more efficiently... please comment if you know how, then I'll edit the post.
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","downloads"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","user_dir"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","user_dir","Default"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")

with open(os.path.join(user_dir, "Default", "Preferences"), "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(default_preferences))


async def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_dir, accept_downloads=True, headless=False, slow_mo=1000)
    browser.set_default_timeout(10000)
    page = await browser.new_page()

    # Start waiting for the download
    file_name = "test_d.pdf"
    async with page.expect_download() as download_info:
        await page.goto("https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", timeout= 5000)
        await page.wait_for_timeout(200)
        print("Saving file to ", downloads_path, file_name)
        # Wait for the download to start
        download = await download_info.value
        # Wait for the download process to complete
        print(await download.path())
        # Save downloaded file somewhere
        await download.save_as(os.path.join(downloads_path, file_name))

    await browser.close()

async def main() -> None:
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Help will be appreciated.

I keep getting the following error after trying sync, async etc. code.  Another alternative is likely to intercept the blob transfer, but I don't know how that's done.  Please advise.

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", waiting until "load"
============================================================
```

Comment: I managed to temporarily fix this error by wrapping the download function in the except portion of a try/except method, although I doubt it's the correct way to go about it.  Please comment if you have advice on how to help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it in the end as explained in my comment of original post.  This is probably not the best way to do it, but it worked.  Please comment if you can improve on using the try/except methods for the download portion of the pdf.

```
from playwright.async_api import Playwright, async_playwright, expect
import asyncio
import os
import json

tmp_dir = './pwtest/'
user_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","user_dir")
print("User dir: ", user_dir)
downloads_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","downloads")
print("Downloads path: ", downloads_path)
storage_state_path = "./pwtest/"
# os.makedirs(os.path.join(tmp_dir, user_dir), exist_ok=True)

default_preferences = {
    "plugins": {
        "always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
}
#Making directories can likely be done more efficiently... please comment if you know how, then I'll edit the post.
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","downloads"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","user_dir"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"pwtest","user_dir","Default"))
except:
    print("Unable to create folder... Likely it already exists.")

with open(os.path.join(user_dir, "Default", "Preferences"), "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(default_preferences))


async def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_dir, accept_downloads=True, headless=False, slow_mo=1000)
    browser.set_default_timeout(10000)
    page = await browser.new_page()

    # Start waiting for the download
    file_name = "test_d.pdf"
    async with page.expect_download() as download_info:
        try:
            await page.goto("https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", timeout= 0)
        except:
            print("Saving file to ", downloads_path, file_name)
            # Wait for the download to start
            download = await download_info.value
            # Wait for the download process to complete
            print(await download.path())
            # Save downloaded file somewhere
            await download.save_as(os.path.join(downloads_path, file_name))
        await page.wait_for_timeout(200)

    await browser.close()

async def main() -> None:
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: couldn't understand the logic behind this, but saved my day. many thanks!

Comment: @BaşarSöker, even though I wrote the code, I also do not understand the logic, and is not the most elegant, but it was the only solution that worked for me. May be a Playwright error, I have too little experience to really know why the standard download functionality for pdf's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The page is taking too much time to load all js content. Change the default time out to zero. So, that there will be no timeout.

Comment: Thanks! I've sped up my retrieval time from around 200 pdf's per minute to roughly around 2000 by decreasing the timeout in page.goto() to 'timeout=1'

Comment: I tried setting both the `page.set_default_timeout()` and `page.goto()` timeouts, but it still gives me this same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @kmancusi see my answer - you need to wrap the download portion of the code in the except portion of a try/except method, that works for me, but don't know if it's the best way to do it.